# Pdx serializing in replicated region using ClientCache

Tags: geode

I have a problem with PDX serialization on a remote Geode instance when using SB to create a Geode client cache as ->

```
@Configuration
public class GeodeClientConfiguration {

@Bean
ClientCache cache() {
    return new ClientCacheFactory()
        .setPdxPersistent(true)
        .setPdxDiskStore("foo")
        .setPdxReadSerialized(true)
        .setPdxSerializer(new ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer(false, "foo.EpgProgram"))
        .create();
}

@Bean
Region<String, List<EpgProgram>> testRegion(final ClientCache cache) {
    return cache.<String, List<EpgProgram>> getRegion("schedule");
}
```

The cache.xml looks like ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client-cache
    xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache
                    http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
<pool name="serverPool">
    <locator host="localhost" port="10334"/>
</pool>
<region name="schedule"  refid="CACHING_PROXY">
    <region-attributes pool-name="serverPool"
            scope="global" />
</region>
```

In Gfsh I have created a region as

```
create region --name=/schedule --type=REPLICATE_PERSISTENT
```

When adding a List of EpgProgram to the region during testing in the method

```
public List<EpgProgram> getScheduleFromWhatson(String channel, LocalDate broadcastDate, Boolean expand) throws RestClientException, URISyntaxException {
    List<EpgProgram> programs = transform(whatsOnServiceInternal.getScheduleFromWhatson(channel, broadcastDate), expand);
    schedule.put(channel, programs);
    return programs;
}
```

The pdx instance seems to get generated using reflection from what I can see from the info trace ->

```
[info 2016/12/09 11:32:33.361 CET <http-nio-8080-exec-1> tid=0xc8] Auto serializer generating type for class dk.dr.epg.core.EpgProgram for fields: 
printable: private boolean dk.dr.epg.core.EpgProgram.printable
live: private boolean dk.dr.epg.core.EpgProgram.live
rerun: private boolean dk.dr.epg.core.EpgProgram.rerun
```

But just after that I get an exception ->

```
org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxInitializationException: The PDX metadata must be persistent in a member that has persistent data. See CacheFactory.setPdxPersistent.
```

Have missed any other place where I have to set Pdx persistense ??

Geode version: 1.0.0-incubating.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the pdx registry to be persistent on the server. You can do that in gfsh like this:

gfsh> configure pdx --disk-store=DEFAULT

I think you need to restart the server after that for the changes to take effect.